# STM32F4 serial RXNE flag

Tags: microcontroller, serial, stm32, uart

I am trying to receive serial on a stm32f411.

I decided to monitor the the RXNE flag to check the serial buffer. I can get the flag to work, however, the issue is that I do not think it is working completely.

I set up a test to increment a counter based on how many times I need to read the DR register. The issue is I cannot get it to increment the counter more than once. To verify this, I simply made a loop to turn on an LED based on how many times I accessed the DR register.The max I can make the LED Blink is 2 times. Is my logic in my code wrong?

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

#include <stdbool.h>

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
uint8_t pdiddy_increment = 0;

int pdiddy[15];
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
void Error_Handler(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

// detect if anything is in serial buffer
uint8_t Serial_Available(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    uint32_t RX_State;

    RX_State = huart->Instance->SR & UART_FLAG_RXNE;

    //something is in the buffer 
    if (RX_State > 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    //nothing is there 
    return 0;
}
/* USER CODE END 0 */

int main(void)
{
  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();

  while (1)
  {
      while (Serial_Available(&huart1))
      {
        /*read DR and put value in array*/
        /*Reading DR, increment shift*/
        pdiddy[pdiddy_increment] = (uint8_t)(huart->Instance->DR & (uint8_t)0x00FF);
        pdiddy_increment++;
     }

     while (pdiddy_increment > 0)
     {
       HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
       HAL_Delay(400);
       HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
       HAL_Delay(400);
       pdiddy_increment--;
     }
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Comment: Set the compiler options to no optimization and see if that works for you. I don't see anything terribly wrong with the logic, but I see a lot of places where the compiler might optimize your code in such a way where it doesn't do what you think it ought to do.

Comment: You have `huart` and not `huart1` in your main loop, does it compile at all?

Comment: My bad...I actually combined my code a little bit so I could make it more concise for easier reading. Yes, it does compile. In the original code reading the DR and increment was in a separate function that accepted the usart handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is written with the implicit assumption of a serial FIFO, but that FIFO is only 1-deep in hardware, and has not been extended to a larger size in software.

The first element of your `while()` loop checks to see if a character has been received, and if so will increment your counter, but it can only increment it once.

Next your code enters a **blocking** drain loop that will not exit until the counter has been drained to zero.

During the blocking drain loop, any number of serial characters could be received, but because the hardware only has a single holding register, the hardware can only indicate a few distinct things:

1. No character has been received
2. One character has been received
3. A character has been received and then the register has overflowed because another was received before it was emptied.
4. A serial formatting error has occurred, with or without some of these other things.

When your code that checks the serial gets to run again, it can only correctly interpret the first two of these states - so the only thing it can possibly do is to increment the counter **by one**, or not - no other increment is possible.

If you want to count characters that come in during a blocking LED flash sequence, you will need to use a serial receive interrupt.  Or you could do the LED flashing in a non-blocking state machine, in a loop that also polled the serial.

Comment: Wouldn't the flag not be set until the serial string is done and read into the DR register X number of times (X being the length of the string, thus incrementing X times)? That is the assumption I made. Is this a bad assumption to make? Do I need to figure out what the number of bytes being received is before hand?

Comment: The UART has no concept of "strings".  Spend some time with the data sheet or programmer's manual understanding the stark, limited meaning of its flags. It can basically hold one complete character you haven't claimed yet, but if it finishes receiving another before you do, you'll lose data.  There do exist chips with deeper hardware FIFOs, but I don't believe this is one of them or at the least you are not operating it in a mode that would utilize any such capability.